# Reading and writing an XML file with PHP

Tags: php, xml

I have 2 text boxes and a radio button. When the user clicks submit I it to generate a XML file with the fallowing format.

```
<object>
    <string1>$string1</string1>
    <string2>$string2</string2>
    <bool>$myBoolean</bool>
</object>
```

After that I want to be able to read through the file and display it.

Comment: How do you need it displayed? In a console window, a GUI, a webpage, or another form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) should get you up and running.